# Получить элемент вложенного массива по заданному пути

Tags: php

Даны два массива,
первый:

```
$array = [
    'one' => 'a',
    'two' => [
        'default' => 'b',
            'three' => [
                'default' => 'c', 
                'four' => 'd'
            ],
    ],
];
```

второй:

```
$p = ['two', 'three', 'default'];
```

Нужно получить из первого массива значение, путь до которого записан во втором массиве. В данном примере это **c**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getElementByPass($arr, $pass) {
    $result = $arr;
    foreach($pass as $index) {
        $result = $result[$index];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Должно сработать ([ideone](https://ideone.com/46I6RN))

Ps. Оборачивайте в Try\catch, чтобы не было внезапных ошибок, когда путь не найден.

Comment: Проверил, работает